# JWT Authentication not working when trying to access a page directly with valid token; will work when starting at login. React/Node/Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I have a login that generates a JWT, then a middleware that verifies the token taken from the headers. The token is also stored in localStorage on the client side as recommended. The problem is that Login works correctly, the "is-verified" returns true but when trying to

1. reload the page or
2. access the dashboard directly with a valid token, instead of accessing from the login page.
   the error occurs with "jwtExpired" in postman or "Not Authorized (authorization not jwt Token)"{(see below)}

When using postman and running the static files is when this behavior occurs; it does not occur when running "npm start.". I will copy the token generated in postman and place it in the headers and try to GET "/dashboard" and leaves me with the same error. Also, it console.error's "jwtExpired." I have checked and rechecked the token and it is correct. After many SO questions and docs I must be missing something on the server side. The error occurs in this middleware file authorization.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
try {

// step 1 destructure
const jwtToken = req.header("token")

if(!jwtToken){
    return res.status(403).json("Not Authorized (authorization not jwt Token)")
/////////////////This is where the program stops when reloaded or accessed directly 
}
// step 2 check if the token is valid 
const payload = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.jwtSecret)
// step 3 gives access as req.user
req.user = payload.user
next()

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    return res.status(403).json("Not Authorized (authorization catch)")
}
}
```

Starting from my server.js file:

```
const express= require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const path = require('path')

// middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

// ROUTES
// register and login
 app.use("/auth", require("./routes/jwtAuth"))
 app.use("/dashboard", require("./routes/dashboard"))

 app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build/index.html"));
   });

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

 app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
 })
```

Login, register and/or check authorization with jwtAuth.js (validInfo just checks for correct email address):

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const pool = require("../db")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const jwtGenerator = require("../utils/jwtGenerator")
const validInfo = require("../middleware/validInfo")
const authorization = require("../middleware/authorization")
// registering
router.post("/register", validInfo, async(req, res) =>{
try {
    
    // step1 destructure
        const { name, email, password } = req.body
        
    // step2 check if the user exists 
        const user = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=$1", [email])
        if(user.rows.length >0){
            return res.status(401).json("User already exists; email is already registered with the 
database")
        }

    // step3 bcrypt the user password for db 
        const saltRound = 10;
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRound)

        const bcryptPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

    // step4 insert the info into the db 
        const newUser = await pool.query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_password) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *", [name, email, bcryptPassword])
   
    // step5 generate a jwt token 
        const token = jwtGenerator(newUser.rows[0].user_id, newUser.rows[0].user_name)
        res.json({ token })

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    res.status(500).json("Server Error (register)")
}
})

// login and logout 
router.post("/login", validInfo, async (req, res) => {
try {
    // step1 deconstruct req.body 
        const { email, password } = req.body
    // step 2 check if user doesnt exist and if not throw and error 
        const user = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=$1", [email])
        if(user.rows.length === 0){
            return res.status(401).json("User email is incorrect or does not exist.")
        }
    // step 3 check if incoming pword is the same as db password 
        const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.rows[0].user_password)
        if(!validPassword){
            return res.status(401).json("Password is incorrect.")
        }
    // step4 give them a jwt token 
    const token = jwtGenerator(user.rows[0].user_id, user.rows[0].user_name)
    res.json({ token })
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.Message)
    res.statusMessage(500).json("Server Error (login)")
}
})

router.get("/is-verified", authorization, (req, res) => {
try {
    res.json(true)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(err.Message)
    res.statusMessage(500).json("Server Error (is-verified)")
}
})

module.exports = router;
```

here is the dashboard.js db and connections:

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const pool = require("../db")
const authorization = require("../middleware/authorization")

// all connections and name
router.get("/", authorization, async (req, res) => {
try {
  res.json(req.user.name)
    if(req.user.name === 'lead'){
      const lead = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM connections LEFT JOIN 
   users ON users.user_id = connections.user_id")                                                                                                      
   ... A bunch of sql queries here that work fine...
      res.json({
        admin: req.user.name,
        results: lead.rows,
        // aggregated queries
        studentsEngaged: studentsEngaged.rows,
        gender:gender.rows,
        distinctStudents: distinctStudents.rows,
        amountSep: amountSep.rows,
        amountOct:amountOct.rows,
        amountNov: amountNov.rows,
        amountDec: amountDec.rows,

        studentSessions:studentSessions.rows,
        homeVisits: homeVisits.rows,
        outsideAgencies: outsideAgencies.rows,
        cpReferrals: cpReferrals.rows,
        amountReferrals:amountReferrals.rows,
        amountDischarges: amountDischarges.rows,
        classroomPresentations: classroomPresentations.rows,
        groupSessions: groupSessions.rows,
        checkins: checkins.rows,
        crisisInterventions: crisisInterventions.rows,
        parentContacts: parentContacts.rows,
        meetings : meetings.rows
      })
    }else{
      const user = await pool.query("SELECT u.user_name, c.connection_id, 
c.contact_type, c.contact_method, c.provision, c.connection_date, 
c.student_id, 
c.purpose, c.gender, c.yearGroup, c.school, c.referral_discharge, 
c.cp_referral 
FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN connections AS c ON u.user_id = c.user_id WHERE 
u.user_id= $1", [req.user.id])                                                                                                      
      res.json(user.rows)
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    res.status(500).json("Server Error (dashboard catch)")
}
})

// create connection
router.post("/connections", authorization, async (req, res) => {
try {
  // console.log(req.body);
  const { student_id, contact_type, yearGroup, school, contact_method, 
gender, purpose, provision, connection_date, referral_discharge, cp_referral} 
= 
req.body;
  const newConnection = await pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO connections (user_id, student_id, user_name, contact_type, 
yearGroup, school, contact_method, gender, purpose, provision, 
connection_date, 
referral_discharge, cp_referral) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, 
$10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING *",
    [req.user.id, student_id, req.user.name, contact_type, yearGroup, school, 
contact_method, gender, purpose, provision, connection_date, 
referral_discharge, 
cp_referral]
  );
  res.json(newConnection.rows[0]);
  // console.log(newConnection.rows[0])
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message)
 }
 });

// update connection 
router.put("/connections/:id", authorization, async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { student_id, contact_type, yearGroup, school, contact_method, 
gender, purpose, provision, connection_date, referral_discharge, cp_referral 
} = 
req.body;
  const updateConneciton = await pool.query(
    "UPDATE connections SET student_id=$1, contact_type=$2, yearGroup=$3, 
 school=$4, contact_method=$5, gender=$6, purpose=$7, provision=$8, 
connection_date=$9, referral_discharge=$10, cp_referral=$11 WHERE 
connection_id = 
$12 AND user_id = $13 RETURNING *",
    [student_id, contact_type, yearGroup, school, contact_method, gender, 
purpose, provision, connection_date, referral_discharge, cp_referral, id, 
req.user.id]
  );     

  if (updateConneciton.rows.length === 0) {
    return res.json("This connection is not yours");
  }

  res.json("Connection was updated");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
 });

// delete connection
router.delete("/connections/:id", authorization, async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const deleteConnection = await pool.query(
    "DELETE FROM connections WHERE connection_id = $1 AND user_id = $2 
RETURNING *",
    [id, req.user.id]
  );

  if (deleteConnection.rows.length === 0) {
    return res.json("This connection is not yours");
  }

  res.json("Connection was deleted");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
 }) ;
```

This is my App.js:

```
  function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)

  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean)
  }

  async function isAuth(){
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/auth/is-verified", {
        method:"GET", 
        headers:{token: localStorage.getItem("token") }
      })
      var parseRes = await response.json()

  // if(parseRes === true || parseRes === undefined){
  //     setIsAuthenticated(true)
  // }else{
  //   setIsAuthenticated(false)
  // }
////////this didn't work, just checking which would occur first, error or 
this conditional 
      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true): setIsAuthenticated(false)

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`(App Catch)${err.message}`)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    isAuth()
  })

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Root 
    {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>} />
            <Route exact path="/landing" render={props => !isAuthenticated ? 
    <Landing {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>} />
            <Route exact path="/register" render={props => !isAuthenticated ? 
    <Register {...props} setAuth ={setAuth} />  : <Redirect to='/login'/>} />
        <Route exact path="/login" render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Login 
    {...props} setAuth ={setAuth} auth={isAuthenticated}/> : <Redirect 
    to='/dashboard'/>} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={props => isAuthenticated ? 
    <Dashboard {...props} setAuth ={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/login'/>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
</Fragment>

  );
}

export default App;


enter code here
```

Comment: Have you checked how your token is signed from this file ("../utils/jwtGenerator")? It might be that the token is valid for just a really short period of time

Comment: Yes, given the "jwt expired" I did but if I type in the url for login up to a a day later I have a ternary operator based on the authentication state that redirects to dashboard appropriately. I will include my App.js at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In authorization.js, where the code was breaking, I eliminated the return and status message and used "res.redirect("/");" This causes the program to redirect in each circumstance when 1. the token is not valid 2. there is no token provided in the header. The redirect takes the user back to the landing page, where the localStorage is checked and if the valid token exists will then redirect to dashboard. Ultimately, instead of having a status message returned I redirect back to the dashboard if authorized.